# How to check if there's any odd/even numbers in an Iterable (e.g. list/tuple)?

Tags: python

Suppose we're checking if there's any odd numbers in a `list`. The most direct way is:

```
def has_odd(L):
    for v in L:
        if v % 2 == 1:
            return True
    return False
```

The `has_odd` function checks if there's any odd numbers in a `list`, once an odd number is found, it returns `True`. But this seems a bit verbose. A more concise way using `reduce` is as follow:

```
reduce(lambda res, v: res or bool(v), L, False)
```

But this will iterate through all elements and is unnecessary, because once an odd number is found the result is surely `True`.

So, are there any other ways to do this?

Comment: `any(int(digit) % 2 for digit in str(number))`

Comment: Obviously if `L` is a sequence, correct form is `any(number % 2 for number in sequence)`. I somehow misread a question and  thought you are checking digits in numbers, for numbers in list.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `any()` function to reduce the verbosity:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> any(n % 2 == 1 for n in l)
True
>>>
```

Note however, [`any()` is pretty much the same as you had originally just generalized](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any), so don't expect a speed improvement:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: That _could_ be condensed to `any(n % 2 for n in l)`, or `any(n & 1 for n in l)`, but I guess your version is a little more readable.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, your right. I'm aware I could've reduced it down even more. But, like you said, I think the version I posted is a bit more readable. And it doesn't really come at that much of a cost.

Comment: I have a little question: in the expression `any(n % 2 == 1 for n in l)`, is `n % 2 == 1 for n in l` a `generator`? Shouldn't it be `any((n % 2 == 1 for n in l))`?

Comment: @CharlesDong Your right. it is a generator. The reason it does not need parenthesis around it is because it is the sole argument to `any()`.  If `any()` took more arguments, the expression need parenthesis around it. [Here is what the documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions): _"The parentheses can be omitted on calls with only one argument. See section Calls for details."_.

Answer (score 1):

first of all let's write small indicator function for "oddness" like

```
def is_odd(number):
    return number % 2
```

then we can write our indicator for "has at least one odd number" using [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) with [`imap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap)/[`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

- **Python 2.***

  ```
  from itertools import imap


  def has_odd_number(iterable):
      return any(imap(is_odd, iterable))
  ```
- **Python 3.***

  ```
  def has_odd_number(iterable):
      return any(map(is_odd, iterable))
  ```

or with [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)

```
def has_odd_number(iterable):
    return any(is_odd(number) for number in iterable)
```

Examples:

```
>>> has_odd_number([0])
False
>>> has_odd_number([1])
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way. you can use `not all()`

```
>>> l = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> not all(n%2==1 for n in l)
True
```